# Using setNavigationBarHidden in viewWillAppear doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, hidden, viewwillappear

Assuming we are having three screens that are pushed after one another like this 
A->B->C
And screen A is originally in a tabBar.
The navigation bar should be hidden in screen C and visible in all of the rest.To do this am doing the following

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:NO];
}
```

The viewWillAppear gets called in all of the cases but hiding or showing the navigationBar is not necessarily gets reflected on the UI.
For example if used the back button the navigation bar appears in both A & B but if tapped the tabBarButton ,which causes the app to jump to screen A directly even from screen C, screen A will be missing the navigationBar.
I've check the self.navigatioController and it's initialized and has a value.

I've tried also to set the NavigationBarHidden property in the viewDidAppear but with no luck.

Any help on that issue? what may cause such a weird scenario?

**Edit: Answer**
I discovered the issue.
Screen C is a complex screen of a lot of containers.In one of the containers i was changing the navigationBar state and that affect everything else in the app and caused the weird behaviour and made me unable to control the state by myself.
Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Have you tried to hide it on vc B's `viewDidDissapear` instead?

Comment: Yea i did ,but didn't work also

Comment: `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];` works fine for me when i just simply put it in `viewDidLoad`, you might want to check again if you unhide it somewhere in code

Comment: @Mohammad Allam pls check my answer and let me know if its working..

Answer (score 0):

In both viewController A and viewController B, use this:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: NO animated:NO];
}
```

In viewController c, use this(as mentioned in question):

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: This's exactly what am doing but for some reason it's not working.
it was working before but suddenly it stopped.

Comment: Can u pls post a screenshot of your viewControllers?

Comment: May i know how is that will affect the answer? 
As it's a company property and i won't be able to do so

Comment: I am now working on a sample..After completion i will update my answer..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help,Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue.Screen C is a complex screen of a lot of containers.
in one of the containers i was changing the navigationBar state and that affect everything else in the app and caused the weird beahviour .

Answer (score -2):

Try the following :-

```
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES];
```

in place of  :-

```
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:NO];
```